# How to re-use the filters used in CALCULATE function when adding columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to add some columns in DAX using CALCULATE functions, just like this:

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    Summarize(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            'MY TABLE'
            'MY TABLE'[Year] = 2019,
            'MY TABLE'[Month] = January,
            'MY TABLE'[Flag] = "N",
        ),
        'MY TABLE'[Column 1],
        'MY TABLE'[Column 2],
        'MY TABLE'[Column 3],
        "Calculation", 'MY TABLE'[My Measure],
    ),
    "My Calculation With Filters 1", CALCULATE('MY TABLE'[My Measure 1],[Status]="Open",[Flag]="N"),
    "My Calculation With Filters 2", CALCULATE('MY TABLE'[My Measure 2],[Status]="Open",[Flag]="N"), --Same filters as above
    "My Calculation With Filters 3", CALCULATE('MY TABLE'[My Measure 3],[Status]="Open",[Flag]="N"), --Same filters as above
    "My Calculation With Filters 4", CALCULATE('MY TABLE'[My Measure 4],[Status]="Open",[Flag]="N"), --Same filters as above
    "My Calculation With Filters 5", CALCULATE('MY TABLE'[My Measure 5],[Status]="Open",[Flag]="N"), --Same filters as above
)
```

I wonder which is the best practice when the filters are the same. I mean, is there a way to avoid adding the same filters to each CALCULATE function? I would like to be able to share the filters so that I don't duplicate code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `CALCULATE` function allows a table to be passed as a filter, so you can define this once as a `VAR` and reuse it.

```
CalculatedTable =
VAR FilteredTable =
    FILTER (
        'MY TABLE',
        'MY TABLE'[Status] = "Open" && 'MY TABLE'[Flag] = "N"
        )
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            'MY TABLE',
            'MY TABLE'[Year] = 2019,
            'MY TABLE'[Month] = January,
            'MY TABLE'[Flag] = "N"
        ),
        'MY TABLE'[Column 1],
        'MY TABLE'[Column 2],
        'MY TABLE'[Column 3],
        "Calculation", 'MY TABLE'[My Measure]
    )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Summary,
        "My Calculation With Filters 1", CALCULATE ( [My Measure 1], FilteredTable ),
        "My Calculation With Filters 2", CALCULATE ( [My Measure 2], FilteredTable ),
        "My Calculation With Filters 3", CALCULATE ( [My Measure 3], FilteredTable ),
        "My Calculation With Filters 4", CALCULATE ( [My Measure 4], FilteredTable ),
        "My Calculation With Filters 5", CALCULATE ( [My Measure 5], FilteredTable )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that will not work as I need to calculate based on filters, not apply a filter to the result. I need to get the summarize of a filtered table and then add to that table some calculations based on other filters, and all those filter will be the same. What you propose will summarize and then add calculations (but not based on my filters), and then it will apply the filters, which is not what I need.

Comment: Can you provide an illustrative example including a table, filters, and expressions? It's hard to answer in the abstract.

Comment: Please, have a look to the code now (I edited it). I hope it looks clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Try my edit. If you make the `Summary` table a variable, then it's fixed and won't be affected by the additional filters in the `ADDCOLUMNS` part.

Comment: I guess it will not work due to ADDCOLUMNS returns a table and the first argument of CALCULATE is an expression. But, even if we change CALCULATE to CALCULATETABLE, I would say that won't work because I would be applying the filters after calculating, and I don't even want to bring the columns which I'm filtering by. The key here is that I want to do some calculations based on the same filters, but I don't want to bring the columns which I'm filtering by, and I want to do those calculations for each row of an initial summarize table.

Comment: I think those filters should apply when calculating each of the 5 measures because they're within the evaluation context of `CALCULATETABLE` where they're set. If you try it and it doesn't work, then I need tangible data table(s) to test on rather than shooting in the dark.

Comment: Let's try a workaround: do you know if it is possible to add several calculations based on the same filters in one step? I mean adding as one argument of the ADDCOLUMNS function multiple calculated columns. I can't believe that there is no way to add multiple calculations based on the same filters in one step, but the truth is that I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: The `CALCULATE` function can accept a table as a filter. You can define a filtered table as a variable and then reuse it in each of the added columns. See my edit.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I believe it is good to edit your answer to show only your code below the Edit

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. It seems like it does not make the same calculation when filtering directly than when using a filter variable. If you apply the filter directly in the `CALCULATE`, it does the calculation for each incoming row, so each row will have its own calculation based on the values of the row and the applied filters. On the other hand, if you use the filter variable, it calculates the measure on the filtered table (getting only one result), and therefore each row will have the same calculation result. I didn't know that it worked like that.

Comment: There are multiple filter contexts interacting making things a bit tricky. I'm pretty sure I can figure it out, but not when I don't have anything to test against. An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be extremely useful here.